# chat with multiple sessions using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a private chat module in my website. But I can't get the session of the other user. can any one help me on this?

here's the code:

```
$url1 = 'onclick="window.open(\'../chat/index.php?do=chat&room_owner='.$uname.'&user='.$_SESSION['uname']['username'].'\',\'pop_up\',\'toolbar=no, top=0,location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=600, height=450\')"';
                    $image_path = "images/online.png";
                    $status = 'Online';

1st user(me): ?do=chat&room_owner='.$uname.' >this is working

2nd user(recipient): &user='.$_SESSION['uname']['username'].' > this is not working?
```

Answer (score 0):

what is uname and username for a variable?
how is communication between the two users done?
which chat module are you using?
what exactly is 'not working' in the above question?
what is supposed to be in $_SESSION['uname']['username'] ?
you could actually print out the value of this variable and see if it has any content:

```
echo "debug: ".$_SESSION['uname']['username'];
```

Comment: it's a private chatting module so i need to get the session of the other user. the $_SESSION['uname']['username']; should display the username of the other user.